# adding two float values by using python 3

Tags: floating-point, python-3.6, rounding

I am trying to add a two float values(6.66,12.208) in python3 but it return 19.868000000000002. is it right?  can someone please tell me the reason

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the floating-point value of 4\*0.1 look nice in Python 3 but 3\*0.1 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618943/why-does-the-floating-point-value-of-40-1-look-nice-in-python-3-but-30-1-doesn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: yes... i am facing the same problem. but i didn't get a solution.can you please explain and apply for this example? @Sujit

Comment: @sivaganeshMurugesan there is no solution, it's like an approximation. I doubt you will need numbers that accurate, just round off to the second or third decimal and display your answer. Do you want me to write an answer to display the sum up to the third decimal?

Comment: ohhhh... okay.. Great..! Iam going to try this way. i will let you know if i cant.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue of how numbers are represented in computers in binary and it occurs programming languages. The most prominent example of this is:

```py
0.1 + 0.2
```

You can find more information about this in the following [link](https://0.30000000000000004.com/?fbclid=IwAR3zOEa_WYjX0qfRHW_06Es-GWJGV5QCGdtes79ncyx8Yxt94Wl5BKV00yY).