# If 0.1 can't be represented exactly in binary, why does printing it show "0.1" and not "0.09999999999999998"?

Tags: python, floating-point

Can you please explain to me how a float number is stored in a variable in python (`x=0.1`)?

I am confused about storing floating point arithmetic **vs** storing float.

**I do understand that** : Floating-point numbers are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions ([docs python floatingpoint](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)). Hence, rational numbers (such as 0.1, which is 1/10) whose denominator is not a power of two cannot be exactly represented ([stackoverflow floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

From that, I thought that when I store a float number in variable (`x=0.1`), when I print `x`, I should get `0.09999999999999998`, because in my understanding we can't represent it as `0.1`. But, the result shows that `x` hold `0.1`, and I don't know how?

```py
>>> res = 1-0.9   # 1
>>> x=0.1         # 2
>>> res , x
(0.09999999999999998, 0.1)   #  1 vs 2   :(
```

Comment: I suspect that it's rounding the result 0.09999999999999998 to 15 significant figures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the floating-point value of 4*0.1 look nice in Python 3 but 3*0.1 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618943/why-does-the-floating-point-value-of-40-1-look-nice-in-python-3-but-30-1-doesn) -- "Python tries to find the shortest string that would round to the desired value..."

Comment: to print float value with more decimal places try `format(0.1,'.17f')` which shows '0.10000000000000001' or use Decimal class; e.g. `Decimal.from_float(0.1)`

Comment: http://weitz.de/ieee/ is a nice tool to see how double precision arithmetic works under the hood

Comment: By the way, `0.1` and `1-0.9` yield slightly different values: `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625` vs. `0.09999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375`. `0.1` can only represent one of them exactly (the first). The other must by necessity be displayed with a bunch of unsightly decimal digits.

Comment: @JohnKugelman , thank you very much, this is the response that I am looking for. I understand know. `0.1` and `1-0.9` doesn't have the same value, and it is the same for `0.3` and `1-0.7`.  The response is combined by the response given in the link [duplicate] + your explanation. Thank you.