# Division in Python unintended output

Tags: python-3.x

Working on a problem that uses a ratio of two parameters. I noticed some weird behavior with the division operator `/` with values < 1e-1 that have a multiple of three. For example

`0.075 / 0.025` `0.15 / 0.05` gives the output of `2.9999999999999996`. I can't use this resultant in my solution as I have a check to ensure the ratio is a whole number. These parameters should work and confused about why this is the output.

Whereas something like `0.9 / 0.3` gives the correct output.

Comment: Floating point numbers are a notoriously difficult thing to handle in a discrete math system. There are a number of posts on why this is, and even more books written about it - but suffice to say you might need to round.

Comment: See also: [Why does the floating-point value of 4*0.1...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618943/why-does-the-floating-point-value-of-40-1-look-nice-in-python-3-but-30-1-doesn?noredirect=1&lq=1)